# How to rename block device?

Tags: linux, terminal, webcam

I am using Camorama Webcam Viewer on a Raspberry Pi.
Camorama by default tries to connect to `/dev/video0`.
If it fails, Camorama will immediately exit and say

> Could not connect to video device (/dev/video0). Please check
>   connection.

But sometimes the webcam does not 'go to' /dev/video0, but other names such as /dev/video10, /dev/video12, etc. This only happens when I connect the webcam through two consecutive USB hubs. 
In these cases, Camorama will not work, even though there is a webcam connected to the Raspberry Pi.

So here's my question: **How do I rename a /dev device, or otherwise cause Camorama to recognize my webcam?**

Comment: BTW: this is more a general linux question than a Raspberry Pi question.

Comment: Usually the approach is matching the device and create a dev node symlink of persistent name with a udev rule.

Comment: If this Camorama doesn't even allow you to specify a device, it sucks. Perhaps you can still `mv` the dev node though.

Comment: Not that it matters much to the issue but `/dev/video0` is not a block device.

Answer (score 0):

> This only happens when I connect the webcam through two consecutive USB hubs.

That got me thinking.

I ran `dmesg` and output includes:

```
[11684.915323] usb 1-1.4.3.2: new high-speed USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
[11685.161315] usb 1-1.4.3.2: New USB device found, idVendor=045e, idProduct=0779, bcdDevice= 1.06
[11685.161323] usb 1-1.4.3.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[11685.161329] usb 1-1.4.3.2: Product: Microsoft® LifeCam HD-3000
[11685.161333] usb 1-1.4.3.2: Manufacturer: Microsoft
[11685.161522] usb 1-1.4.3.2: rejected 1 configuration due to insufficient available bus power
[11685.161528] usb 1-1.4.3.2: no configuration chosen from 1 choice
[11685.161532] usb 1-1.4.3.2: No support over 100mA
```

So it looks like the webcam remains undetectable if it goes through two consecutive usb hubs. This was confirmed when it failed to connect to VLC or Chromium.

So camorama was not the problem, but the scapegoat.

Comment: Any way to disable this automatic 'insufficient-current rejection'?